# Evaluating the integral $\int_0^{\infty} dk\frac{\sin(kr)}{k(k^2 + m^2)}$

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I have been trying to solve Poisson's Equation, given by $$\nabla^2\Phi(\vec{r}) = -\frac{\rho(\vec{r})}{\epsilon_0}$$ for the given charge density $$\rho(\vec{r}) = \frac{\rho_0}{m}\frac{e^{-mr}}{r}$$ for positive parameters $\rho_0$ and $m$, subject to the boundary condition that $\Phi(\vec{r})\rightarrow 0$ as $r\rightarrow\infty$.
    To do this, I did a Fourier Transform of the initial equation, which I then solved for the Fourier Transform of $\Phi(\vec{r})$, $\hat{\Phi}(\vec{k})$ to obtain:
    $$\hat{\Phi}(\vec{k}) = \frac{4\pi\rho_0}{m\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{m^2 + k^2}$$
    When applying the Inverse Fourier Transform, the integral in question arises as the last integral to calculate - $\Phi(\vec{r})$ is given by
    $$\Phi(\vec{r}) = \frac{\rho_0}{\pi\epsilon_0 mr}\int_{0}^{\infty}dk\frac{\sin(kr)}{k(k^2 + m^2)}$$
    I have entered this integral into Wolfram Alpha, which gives me the result
    $$\Phi(\vec{r}) = \frac{\rho_0}{\epsilon_0 m^3 r}(1 - e^{-mr})$$
    This agrees with the result one obtains when calculating $\Phi(\vec{r})$ directly using the formula obtained by using the Green Function of the $\nabla^2$-Operator, so I know that it is correct.

However, I'd still be interested in how one would go about evaluating this integral, because none of the integration techniques that I know seem to work at all.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Plancherel's formula
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\overline{f(x)}g(x)\, dx =  \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\overline{F(\xi)}G(\xi)\, d\xi 
\end{equation*}
where $f,g\in L_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and $F(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-i\xi x}\, dx$ (Fourier transform).

If $f(x) = \dfrac{\sin(xr)}{x}$ then $F(\xi) = \pi(H(\xi+r)-H(\xi-r))$, where $H$ is the Heaviside step function. Futhermore, if $g(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^2+m^2}$ then $G(\xi) = \dfrac{\pi}{m}e^{-|m\xi|}$.

Thus
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(xr)}{x(x^2+m^2)}\, dx = \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-r}^{r}\dfrac{\pi^2}{m}e^{-|m\xi|}\, d\xi = \dfrac{\pi}{m}\int_{0}^{r}e^{-m\xi}\, d\xi = \dfrac{\pi}{m^2}(1-e^{-mr}).
\end{equation*}
Finally
\begin{equation*}
\Phi = \dfrac{\rho_{0}}{2\epsilon_{0}m^{3}r}(1-e^{-mr})
\end{equation*}
with an extra 2 factor.

Comment: That's probably the most elegant solution I have seen. And I actually know Plancherel's formula, damn. Thanks a lot! And yeah, I found the missing factor of 2 as well. :)

Comment: @Tom You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. You are in fact interested in evaluating
$$
I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x(x^2 + 1)}\:dx,\qquad a>0.\tag1
$$ Let's consider the  [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) of $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}\:dx$. We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}\:dx\right)(s) & = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}e^{-as}\:da\:dx
\\&= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{s}{(x^2+1)(s^2+x^2)}\;{dx} 
\\&= \frac{\pi}{2(s+1)}
\end{aligned}
$$giving
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}\:dx=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi}{2(s+1)}\right) =\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-a},\qquad a>0, \tag2
$$ then by differentiating $(2)$ with respect to $a$, one gets
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(ax)}{x^2+1}\:dx=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-a},\qquad a>0. \tag3
$$ By partial fraction decomposition we have
$$
\frac{1}{x(x^2+1)}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{x^2+1}
$$ and
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x(x^2 + 1)}\:dx&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}\:dx-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(ax)}{x^2+1}\:dx
\\\\&=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-a},\qquad a>0,
\end{align}
$$ where we have used the classic result
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}\:dx\stackrel{u=ax}{=}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}\:du=\frac{\pi}{2},\qquad a>0.
$$ Finally,

> $$
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x(x^2 + 1)}\:dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(1-e^{-a}\right),\qquad a>0.
> $$

You then get your initial integral with the change of variable, $u=bx$ 
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(a u)}{u(u^2 + b^2)}\:du=\frac1{b^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(abx)}{x(x^2 + 1)}\:dx=\frac{\pi}{2b^2}(1 - e^{-ab})
$$ as announced.

Comment: Interesting approach, thank you. I had thought about differentiating under the integral sign, but I hadn't been able to make that work - seems I didn't think far enough.

Comment: @Tom You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with Residues Calculus?

Your integral is an improper integral with trigonometric function. First of all notice that your function is even, hence you may write

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(kr)}{k(k^2 + m^2)}\ \text{d}k$$

Actually, for those kinds of integral, what we are really doing is to evaluate the so called Principal Value, that is

$$\lim_{R\to\infty} \frac{1}{2}\int_{-R}^{+R} \frac{\sin(kr)}{k(k^2 + m^2)}\ \text{d}k$$

Indeed called the Cauchy principal Value. But let's leave this apart for the moment.

Now you can evaluate it with Residues Theorem. First of all, the sine at the numerator is nothing but the imaginary part of the complex exponential:

$$\sin(kr) = \Im e^{ikr}$$

So we write

$$\frac{1}{2}\Im \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{ikr}}{k(k^2 + m^2)}\ \text{d}k$$

Now the integral has three poles at $k = 0$, $k = +im$ and $k = -im$. Indeed you may rewrite the denominator in a clearer way to see it:

$$\frac{1}{2}\Im \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{ikr}}{k(k+im)(k-im)}\ \text{d}k$$

Hence we have by Residues Calculus

$$\frac{1}{2}\Im\left\{2\pi i \sum_i\ \text{Res}[f(k), k_i]\right\}$$

Where $k_i$ are the poles.

The first pole is at $k = 0$ so we have

$$2\pi i\left(\lim_{k\to 0} k\cdot \frac{e^{ikr}}{k(k+im)(k-im)}\right) = \frac{2\pi i}{im(-im)} = \frac{2\pi i}{m^2}$$

For the other two poles $k = im$ and $k = -im$ we only consider the poles who lie in the upper half plane, hence $k = im$:

$$2\pi i\left(\lim_{k\to im} (k-im)\cdot \frac{e^{ikr}}{k(k-im)(k+im)}\right) = 2\pi i \frac{e^{i(im)r}}{(im)(im + im)} = 2\pi i\frac{e^{-mr}}{2i^2m^2} = -\pi i \frac{e^{-mr}}{m^2}$$

Collecting all the residues together:

$$\pi i\left(\frac{2}{m^2} - \frac{e^{-mr}}{m^2}\right)$$

Hence

$$\frac{1}{2}\Im\left\{2\pi i \sum_i\ \text{Res}[f(k), k_i]\right\} = \frac{\pi}{2m^2}\left(2 - e^{-mr}\right)$$

Using this into your result:

$$\Phi(\vec{r}) = \frac{\rho_0}{\pi\epsilon_0 mr}\int_{0}^{\infty}dk\frac{\sin(kr)}{k(k^2 + m^2)} = \frac{\rho_0}{\pi\epsilon_0 mr}\cdot \frac{\pi}{2m^2}\left(2 - e^{-mr}\right)$$

$$\Phi(\vec{r}) = \frac{\rho_0}{2\epsilon_0 r m^3}\left(2 - e^{-mr}\right)$$

Which is ... not your solution lol.

Something went wrong, somewhere. I will send this answer the same, just to give you some hints and help about how to compute the integral, even if there is that $2$ factor more.

Learn Residues Calculus. It's mandatory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's possible that I also made a mistake when calculating $\Phi(\vec{r})$ directly via the Green Function, which might explain the difference in our results. I've read a little about Residue Calculus, but we haven't had it in our classes yet, so it didn't occur to me that that might be helpful. I'll definitely look into it some.

Comment: @Tom Consider that my answer can be rewritten as

$$\frac{\rho_0}{\epsilon_0 m^3 r}\left(1 - \frac{e^{-mr}}{2}\right)$$

So unless **I** made some mistake, you may check your result again, despite it seems like YOURS is correct xD

Comment: To be clear, you're considering a contour of integration that runs along the real axis and then along a semi-circle in the upper half-plane, which you then take towards infinity to have the contribution of the arc vanish, is that correct? Or am I completely misunderstand that?

Comment: @Tom That is exactly the procedure for the integration of improper trigonometric functions!

Comment: your use of the residue theorem is wrong (to be more concrete, the treatment of the pole at $z=0$), so maybe you should review parts of residue calculus by yourself before posting answers which make use of it.

Comment: @tired You're right, and indeed that was my thought: an error in the calculation of the pole at $z = 0$. When I posted it, I couldn't be able to consult any reference or book, and I couldn't remember how it worked for that part. I'll edit soon.